# how to count the frequency of occurrence of some specific words of my data in hive?

Tags: json, hive, mapreduce

I have a table of twitter objects (json formatted), n rows and 1 column in my hive. The task is to count the frequency of occurrence of some words like 'hon', 'han' in different objects (each object has a attribute called 'text', which includes some texts( string type)), which means even if a word is occurred in an object more than one time, but it only counts one. 
I write a query like below.

```
select count(*) from table_name
where regexp(get_json_object(col_name, '$.text'), 'han')
limit 10
```

And get an error message like

> FAILED: ParseException line 2:6 cannot recognize input near 'regexp' '(' 'get_json_object' in expression specification`

How can I do this query task? And I don't know how to ignore case in the regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `(?i)` modifier for case insensitive compare:

```
select 
      sum(case when text rlike '(?i)han' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_han,
      sum(case when text rlike '(?i)hon' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_hon
  from
(
select get_json_object(col_name, '$.text') as text 
  from table_name
)s;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I tried your code, but get the following error. FAILED: ParseException line 2:9 cannot recognize input near 'sum' '(' 'when' in expression specification.

Comment: And my hive version is 2.3.4

Comment: @SeekerBlood Fixed syntax error: It should be CASE statement

Comment: Thanks mate! It works and gets the same result with my java code! By the way, could I ask what does the 's' mean in the end just before the ';'

Comment: @SeekerBlood It's a subquery name (alias). Hive mandates subquery should have some alias.

Comment: I got it. Thanks again!